# Must FieldOffset be used on every class/struct member if it is used at all?

Tags: c#, marshalling, structlayout

Consider the case where I need to ensure a class/struct is mapped to memory in a very specific way, probably due to the need to match an external protocol:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
public class SYSTEM_INFO
{
 public ulong OemId;
 public ulong PageSize;
 public ulong ActiveProcessorMask;
 public ulong NumberOfProcessors;
 public ulong ProcessorType;
}
```

Then I thought about doing an 'overlay' (is this a proper term?) so I can directly access the memory:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public class SYSTEM_INFO
{
[FieldOffset(0)] public byte[] Buffer = new byte[40]; //overlays all the bytes, like a C union
[FieldOffset(0)] public ulong OemId;
[FieldOffset(8)] public ulong PageSize;
[FieldOffset(16)] public ulong ActiveProcessorMask;
[FieldOffset(24)] public ulong NumberOfProcessors;
[FieldOffset(32)] public ulong ProcessorType;
}
```

But this gets time-consuming and error-prone (if something changes I could easily mess up updating all the `FieldOffset` values) - and has been pointed out is actually not valid for reasons I do not fully understand:

> Unhandled exception. System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'SYSTEM_INFO2' from assembly 'a2bbzf3y.exe, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object
>   field at offset 0 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a
>   non-object field. Command terminated by signal 6

Is it possible to do a combination of both approaches, where `Buffer` overlays the members, but all members *except* `Buffer` are automatically, sequentially aligned without padding? I cannot make out from the docs if this is allowed or not, and I can force some member offsets only with others automatically decided.

Comment: Overlay is the correct terminology.  I think what will work if you have a base class and a class that inherits the base class you can create an overlay.  To have FieldOffset will only work with LayoutKind.Explicit and then each property must have the FieldOffset.

Comment: That `[40]` doesn't compile (C# 7.3).  I *think* you need `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 40)]`:  `[FieldOffset(0), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 40)] public byte[] Buffer;`  I am unsure about that first parameter though.

Comment: @Amy I *believe* they're more intending it to be a "fixed buffer" that happens to span the entire object: `public fixed byte Buffer[40];`

Comment: @MarcGravell I defer to your wisdom here, my experience with marshalling is pretty weak, to be honest.  Should I delete my comment?

Comment: @Amy  I wouldn't (delete it), because I'm pretty sure other readers would have the same thought, so it helps to retain that context / clarification

Answer (score 2):

In the case of a `struct`, you can do this quite easly - and frankly, if you're looking at the bytes, you should *generally* be using a `struct`:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new SystemInfo();
        var bytes = AsBytes(ref obj);
        Console.WriteLine(bytes.Length); // 40
    }

    static Span<byte> AsBytes<T>(ref T value)
        => MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(
            ref Unsafe.As<T, byte>(ref value),
            Unsafe.SizeOf<T>());
}

public readonly struct SystemInfo
{
    public readonly ulong OemId;
    public readonly ulong PageSize;
    public readonly ulong ActiveProcessorMask;
    public readonly ulong NumberOfProcessors;
    public readonly ulong ProcessorType;
}
```

Comment: It's an interesting approach but seems to circumvent rather than directly answer the question in favour of a different approach. It is welcome but I'm still curious in a  more direct answer - this is a whole side of C# I've never worked with